# ResultSet returns empty despite query correctly producing results in SQLiteStudio

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

**Context:**

Local database made with **sqlite3** called **lims.db** which contains a table called **privLevels** with columns **user** storing usernames and **level** storing integers from 0 to 2, but as a string.

```
privLevels
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
user  | level
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
admin | 0
john  | 1
kevin | 2
susan | 1
```

I'm trying to run and *SQL SELECT* query on this table and then pass the results into a Map object, with the values from **user** being the key, and values from **level** being the value.

```
    privMap
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<"admin" = "0">
<"john" = "1">
<"kevin" = "2">
<"susan" = "1">
```

The problem I'm having is that the *ResultSet* generated is returned as completely empty. The while loop in the code below never runs, and in the IntelliJ debugger, the *ResultSet* object is empty. In *SQLiteStudio*, the query runs correctly. In the rest of my code, statements run fine, but queries don't.

**Code:**

getPrivMapFromDatabase() should work - if the *ResultSet* contained anything. It gets the value from user and level and then .puts() them into the Map.

```
 public void getPrivMapFromDatabase() {
     ResultSet results = Base.getStringMapFromDatabase("privLevels", "user", "level");
     try {
         while(results.next()) {
           String user = results.getString("user");
           System.out.println(user);
           String level = results.getString("level");
           System.out.println(level);
           privMap.put(user, level);
         }
     }
     catch (SQLException e) {
         System.out.println("[EXCEPTION] " + e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

These methods are in the "Base" class.

I wrote *getStringMapFromDatabase()* like this because I need to do the same thing to another table and map. It should generate the string (which I checked is syntactically correct) and then execute it.

*executeQuery()* should just run the query and then return the *ResultSet* to *getPrivMapFromDatabase()*. However, the *ResultSet* object is empty. **CREATE / INSERT statements work fine** (using a seperate methods for running statements).

```
 private static String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/#My_Username#/IdeaProjects/#Project_Name#/sqlite/db/lims.db";

 //Username and project name redacted

 public static ResultSet getStringMapFromDatabase(String table, String keyColumn, String valueColumn) {
     String sql = "SELECT " + keyColumn + ", " + valueColumn + " FROM " + table + ";";
     return executeQuery(sql);
 }

 public static ResultSet executeQuery(String sql) {
     ResultSet results = null;
     try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
          Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
         results = statement.executeQuery(sql);
     }
     catch (SQLException exception) {
         System.out.println("[EXCEPTION] " + exception.getMessage());
     }
     return results;
 }
```

Why is the ResultSet coming back empty, even though the query runs fine in SQLiteStudio and other statements work? The table name, and column names are correct.

Comment: Could you show the query that works when you run it against SQLite?  If the number of tables you have to do this against is small have you considered providing a map of `PreparedStatements`?

Comment: Having just refreshed my memory, and perhaps nightmares of the `ResultSet` you might be able to get more information about what happened  to your query by calling ```getStatement``` this should give you information about the statement that was used to execute the result set, and there might be something useful in the metadata returned by ```getMetaData```.  I am not convinced you can get an ```int``` as a ```String```` from the ```ResultSet``` (its been awhile since i used JDBC), and there really isint any need as you can convert it in Java as needed or define the column as a ```varchar```